# How to select building target in QT Creator?

Tags: qt, build, compilation

I am trying to set up and run an open source application([**LibreCAD**](http://librecad.org/cms/home.html)) and I am following their **[Build From Source](http://wiki.librecad.org/index.php/Build_from_source)** guide. In section "*Building LibreCAD 2.0 on Windows*" and under "*Building LibreCAD in Qt-Creator*" they state this:

> - Take care about the Shadow build option in Debug and Release
>     configuration. Disable this option in both configurations and save the
>     project.
> - **Select librecad as building target in Qt Creator (instead of tff2lff, which is another choice)**
> - If everything is good up to this point, you can build and run LibreCAD
>     within Qt-Creator.

I could not figure out how or/and where to do the second task. Could anyone help me please?

In [Qt - Building for Multiple Platforms](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-building-targets.html) they say I need to "*1.Click the Build and Run Kit Selector icon*" and then to "*2.Choose Build > Build Project*". But I don't see any **Kit Selector** icon on my QT compiler!

And in [Configuring Projects](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-configuring-projects.html) they say it is right here:

[image]

But on mine, it looks like disabled:

[image]

**Edit:**

This is how my "Kit Selector" looks like:

[image]

Comment: From my understanding, you do not need to switch to another kit, if you already have one that meets minimal requirements for the LibreCAD (looks like Qt5.4 from their web site). You already have Qt 5.7.0 kit installed that I can see from the second screenshot you provided. The "building target" is an unclear instruction and looks more like a "Run configuration"(?) to me. Did you try to start the build by skipping the second step? Also have look here: http://librecad.org/cms/home/from-source/windows.html - it has some screenshots, although for windows, it does not mention any "build target".

Comment: Yes I tried skipping it (which is the case now). It builds fine, and when I press run it loads and finishes but nothing really happen (Not sure exactly what is causing this so I thought of perfecting it and select the platform). Thank you for the link, I will clean and restart the whole attempt and see how it goes.

Comment: Then it is, probably, indeed the "Run configuration" they talk about, not "build config". You should try to use "Release" mode and then switch the "Run configuration" to the "librecad". I assume, nothing happens in your case because you do not change your run from the default "tff2lff" to "librecad"

Comment: Are you sure you're opening the [root `.pro`](https://github.com/LibreCAD/LibreCAD/blob/master/librecad.pro) file and not the [leaf project](https://github.com/LibreCAD/LibreCAD/blob/master/librecad/librecad.pro)?

Comment: @Mitch yes definitely. See here https://postimg.org/image/tugfvqn0l/

Comment: @vicrucann I see but how to do that? "_switch the "Run configuration" to the "librecad"_" and I want to be able to change code and test it (debug) and once I am finished to create a Release. Similar to the usage of Visual Studio. Are we on the right track?

Comment: @FirstStep : Sure you can run it in debug if you wish. To change the "run configuration", you can do it: Qt creator side bar, "Projects" -> click on "Run" (next to "Build" option on your 2nd screenshot) option and you will find "Run configuration" there.

Comment: You don't seem to need to do anything at all. You appear to be all set. What exactly doesn't work for you?

Comment: The options are disabled for you because you only have one kit. That's fine.

Comment: @KubaOber Well, the problem is that when I RUN nothing happens. If I BUILD, it takes like 10 mins then it finishes fine. If I RUN, it takes like 1 mins and it finishes. But nothing really happens (pops up). Also if I go and double click on the .exe (after BUILD) I get three errros saying "_The procedure entry point _Z20qt_qFindChild_helperPK7QObjectRK7QMetaObj... chars here .... could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Users.......LibreCAD.exe_"

Comment: You won't be able to run the `.exe` file manually because Qt Creator puts the Qt from the selected kit into the path. In the run options of the project you're able to select which target you want to run. Make sure you've selected the correct target.

Comment: @KubaOber but in the RUN Settings, I don't see any "suspicion".. you know. All look normal.. And nothing is called "Target" stuff. And what should I do to be able to create a working .exe? (so when I change the code I want to be able to use a .exe on another device). EDIT: btw this is my first ever on QT so excuse me being so noob..

Comment: You need to learn how to deploy Qt executables. windeployqt is a tool that helps with that, but you'll have to make an installer anyway and learn what goes where.

Answer (score 2):

> and then to "Choose Build > Build Project"

I'm not sure where you see that, but it's not on either of those pages.

They're talking about this thingy:

[image: creator screenshot]

The "Build and Run Kit Selector icon" is on the button above the "Run" button (it's probably named like this because running an executable via this button implies that the target is built first).

In your project, `tff2lff` might be where `app` is in the screenshot, and `librecad` might be where `test` is, for example.

Comment: It is `2.` step two in the second link. Please see Edit, mine looks completely different. Also I replied to an OP comment maybe it is helpful to read it please